# Why won't this angular-translate example show translated text?

Tags: angularjs, angular-translate

In the following file I would expect it to show the translation "This is a headline" but it shows nothing.

What do I have to change so this code shows the translation "This is a headline"?

```
<html ng-app="mainApp">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.26/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.12.0.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bower-angular-translate/2.5.2/angular-translate.min.js"></script>
    </head>    
    <body ng-controller="mainController">

        <div>[{{message}}]</div>
        <div>[{{HEADLINE| translate}}]</div>

        <script>
                            var mainApp = angular.module('mainApp', ['pascalprecht.translate']);
                            mainApp.config(function ($translateProvider) {

                                $translateProvider.translations('en', {
                                    HEADLINE: 'This is the headline',
                                    INTRO: 'This is the intro'
                                }).translations('de', {
                                    HEADLINE: 'Dies ist die Kopfzeile',
                                    INTRO: 'Dies ist die Einführung'
                                });
                                $translateProvider.preferredLanguage('en');
                            });


                            mainApp.controller('mainController', function ($scope, $translate) {
                                $scope.message = 'testing';
                            });


        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: `[{{HEADLINE| translate}}]` Typo or space before | missing?

Comment: is there any console error?

Comment: argh, it should be 'HEADLINE' instead of HEADLINE, fixed, thanks.